# how would I write "while( x/y is not a multiple of 4)"

Tags: c, do-while, modulo

I am relatively new to programming  and I want to it to loop in a "do while" loop while the quotient of two variables is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: `while ((x / y) % 4).nonzero?`

Comment: @ForeverZer0 What version of C has `.nonzero`?

Comment: @Barmar None lol, I had at first thought it was Ruby tag, I corrected obviously in my answer. I would hope that `nonzero?` can still be figured out without explicit and long explanations.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Yeah, "new to programming" means he probably can't figure out anything. :) Didn't notice you also posted a better answer.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? Are they always integers? You are just saying "variables".

Comment: Do you want to test whether the mathematical quotient *x* / *y* is not a multiple of four or whether the quotient `x / y` computed with integer arithmetic (hence the mathematical quotient truncated to an integer) is not a multiple of four? For example, the mathematical 21/5 is not a multiple of 4, but the computed `21/5` is.

Answer (score 1):

The `modulo` operator, or `%` will do exactly as you need. It will return the "remainder" of dividing a number by a given value. Using that logic, if the result is `0`, then the specified number was divided evenly by the value.

Therefore:

```
do
{
    // do stuff that changes x and/or y
} while ((x / y) % 4) != 0)
```

Should accomplish your goals.
You divide your `x/y` value, and then use `% 4` on the result. If the result is zero, then the it was evenly divisible by 4, if it is not zero, there was a remainder and it was not evenly divisible.

As pointed out in a comment below, the `do...while` syntax first "does", **then** evaluates, which although not indicated in your question, is unlikely the intended behavior, and what you need is simply a `while` loop without the `do`. This first evaluates, and then "does" only if the result was `true`, otherwise does nothing.

```
while (y != 0 && (x / y) % 4) != 0)
{
    // do stuff that changes x and/or y
}
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged as C, you probavly should adjust the syntax of your while loop.

Comment: I could have swore that it was tagged Ruby when I read it, lol, Fixed  it.

Comment: The question language is not clear about the requirements, but note that this will evaluate the modulo at the end, which means the last iteration will operate under the condition of x/y%4 == 0, and then exit.

Comment: Yeah, I perhaps should clarify that, I simply made it as the question stated, although it is probably unlikely to be the way it should be.

Comment: @visibleman That loop will only operate with (x/y)%4==0 on the very first iteration, and halt if (x/y)%4 is still zero after that first iteration.  That's the _only_ way to run with the condition tue on the _last_ iteration.

Comment: If the OP is a programming noob, you might want to mention checking for `y` value of zero to avoid `x/y` division by zero.

Comment: The mathematical quotient of 17/4 is 4.25, yet `int x,y; ... (x / y) % 4` is 0.  I suspect for OP's goal,17,4 should fail, not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the math. Let Z = X / Y. Then you want Z % 4 to be non-zero.

Answer (score -2):

try like this.You can use z to store result of (x/y)%4.

```
main(){
int x=0,y=0, z=0;
  do{ // do anything 

  }
  while((x/y)%4 != 0);
}
```

Comment: someOne downvoted only exact answer written in c?

Comment: I don't downvote but I would say it deserves one. There is no return value and no argument declaration in your `main`. I advise that you compile your source code with `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra`. :)

Comment: Your code has no explanation why this is a solution, and it mentions using a variable to store the result but doesn't actually do that. Whether the code is correct or not it isn't going to teach anyone anything.

Comment: I also didn't down-vote, but your answer mentions using z, but then your code does not use z for anything.

Comment: Nor did I down-vote. But what if the "do anything" doesn't change `y`? Then `x/y` will be a division by zero.